# Delete all files with certain properties in Python

Tags: python, file, directory

How would you delete in `Python` all files in directory `/tmp/dir` and all its subdirectories that have extension `.txt` or `.mp3`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module at all?

Comment: Does it have to be python? `find . -name \*.mp3 -exec rm {} \;`.

Comment: Why was this so heavily downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `os.walk` to traverse recursively a directory and `os.remove` when you find a file whose name matches your requirements.

Note that `os.walk` returns on one hand file names and, on the other hand, a root directory. Hence, for the `os.remove` to work you'll need to create the full filename with `os.path.join`.